# Securing a python Application

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.6, python-import

I am using a mongoDB(`pymongo`) where I have the python source (the logic of the program) stored as a b64 String.

After giving a valid key, I fetch the b64 String and decode it.

---

Example:

```
data : "cHJpbnQoImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIik="

data : "print("hello world")"
```

How can I `import` the fetched source(`data`) to my existing python file, without locally storing it in a file to use it's functions?

---

### Edit:

The `mongodb` is on a server. The Python program fetches the dataset with the given key from the server.

```
base64.b64decode(data.find_one({ "key": "derp"})['data'])
```

=> `data = print("hello world")`

the above command is called from `main.py`. To "work" properly / use certain program features, the `data (logic.py)` has to be injected into the `main.py`, so main.py can use it's functions etc.

logic.py

```
def sayHello():
  print("hello world")
```

main.py

```
    def doRegisterStuff():
    [...]
#worked
import logic #import the decoded base64 string to use its function
    logic.sayHello()
```

Comment: Please explain more how you mean to use this? Is the database on another computer I'm just not sure I'm following what you mean by "without locally storing it in a file to use it's functions"

Comment: Also, I don't know why you're insisting on tagging import, it's unrelated to what you're asking

Comment: @Jaba is it clearer now?

Comment: I find it funny when people are talking about security and Python.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It sounds horrible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman prevent from RE'ing

Comment: If your concern is reverse engineering - do not use Python. Use any of the languages that are able to build into optimized executable binary.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

[exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is exactly what I needed.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    exec(base64.b64decode(ex.licenses.find_one({ "key": "derp"})['data']))
    sayHello()
```